# Visual Studio Keyboard Shortcut for Joining Lines

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio

Does Visual Studio have a way of joining lines?

I want the same functionality that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> provides in Sublime Text

Comment: Ctrl-J mapped to join lines?  How is that "close" to deleting a line? Maybe you need to define what ctrl-j does for you, perhaps you have it remapped.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3835523/does-visual-studio-2010-not-have-a-join-lines-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/76293c4d-8c16-4f4a-aee6-21f83a571496

Answer (score 2):

Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboad -> Edit.JoinLines

Assign your new shortcut if none set (can choose the "Use new shortcut in:" to be set to "Text Editor") to configure context where we want to use the shortcut

[image: JoinLines keyboard shortcut snapshot]

P.S.: Remember to ensure any extension is not overriding the mapping (e.g. Resharper)

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not -- I'd love to know why.

[This](https://github.com/wmaurer/vscode-join-lines) extension adds such support.